# Where does PERSISTENT file system storage store with chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, filesystems, html5-filesystem

[When doing `webkitRequestFileSystem` in `window.PERSISTENT` option](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) in Google Chrome, where on my filesystem do files get written?  I'd like to drop files there and have Chrome interact with them while I'm building and debugging this app.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For me, at least on Mac OSX, they're stored under `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System` for me. If you're using profiles, there will be profile directories instead of `Default`. However, each origin's saved files/folders are obfuscated under directories that won't be easy for you to interact with.

For debugging the Filesystem API, you have a few options:

1. Use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nhnjmpbdkieehidddbaeajffijockaea) to view/remove files.
2. See the tips here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Debugging-the-Filesystem-API
   That includes viewing stored files very easily using the `filesystem:` URLs.
3. Drop the Filesystem Playground demo (http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/filesystem/filer.js/demos/index.html) into your origin. You can use that to view/rename/delete files/folders easily.
4. Chrome DevTools now has support for the Filesystem API for viewing the files stored under an origin. To use that, you will need to enable the Developer Tools experiments in `about:flags`, restart, hit the gear in the devtools (lower right corner), and enable the 'FileSystem inspection' under the experimental tab.

Comment: Does the extension work with the webkit fileSystem? I am using it and it doesn't. It only works for me when using localStorage.

Comment: Currently (at the moment I'm writing this) [that extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nhnjmpbdkieehidddbaeajffijockaea) doesn't work with chrome extensions but with sites only.

Comment: I use persistent file system just before recording audio. But my cordova app works fine in ios 6 & 7 versions but fails in ios8.

Comment: @ebidel, "FileSystem inspection" where? Seems to be gone.

Comment: Yea, looks like they removed the experiment from DevTools

Comment: @ebidel, Link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nhnjmpbdkieehidddbaeajffijockaea down too.

Comment: I ended up using `filesystem:http://localhost/persistent/file_name123` to display the file but it's completely useless for huge files.

Answer (score 20):

Just for completeness: on linux it goes into ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/File\ System/

Answer (score 18):

On Windows XP, it is here: `c:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System\`.

On Windows 7, the location is `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System`.

It's not very useful to browse it because file and dir names are obfuscated (but content in files is unchanged).

As ebidel wrote the best way is using browser of `filesystem:` urls that incorporated into Chrome. It's excellent! You can get the url using `fs.root.toURL()` where `fs` is a FileSystem object that you get, for example, from `window.webkitRequestFileSystem()`.

Comment: If you get the URL via `fs.root.toURL()`, then you can also open it in the browser to explore your files. I tried it with a temporary storage url (`filesystem:http://localhost:63342/temporary/`) and it worked just fine in Chrome 65.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like the filesystem storage is encoded to prevent exactly what was trying to do. I ended up writing a very [simple file manager available here](https://bitbucket.org/togakangaroo/filesystemstoragetests). Start up any web server (I like [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) for its 0 setup) and go to the `/filemanager.html route`

Answer (score 2):

I saved a file called log.txt on MAC

It ended up at
~/Library/Application\Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Storage/ext/panbljeniblfmcakpphmjmmnpcaibipi/def/File\ System/iso/p/00/

with file name 00000 and no ext

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAC OX, and you have more than one profile on your chrome, or you cannot find default in the path, replace `default` with `profile`. But depending on number of profiles you have, it could be `profile 1`, `profile 2`, etc