# How to test reading of files in Blackberry Ripple Emulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am attempting to build an app that needs to read .epub files on a Blackberry using WebWorks. However, using the Ripple Emulator I'm able to access the directory structure in blackberry.io.dir but I wanted to make a file available to be read so I can test the loading of a file.

I assume the folders like file:///SDCard are not physical folders but is there anyway I can copy a file from my local machine to this folder so I can begin testing.

I tried using local:/// but this is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what OS you're on but this answer talks about Mac OS: [Where does PERSISTENT file system storage store with chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676584/where-does-persistent-file-system-storage-store-with-chrome)