# fileSystem API - Where is the save directory?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to save a file by using fileSystem api.

It seems that this code below works fine.

But, I can't find where the saved file is located.

It should be located in the following directory if it's in mac os??

/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System/

I'm almost done with my project. All I have to do is implementing the function to save files in local drive!

please help me out!!

Thanks!

```
function writeToLocal(filename, content) {

    function errorCallback(e) {
        alert("Error: " + e.name);
    }

function fsCallback(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile(filename, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                alert("Success! : " + fileEntry.fullPath);
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                alert("Failed: " + e);
            };

            var output = new Blob([content], {type: "text/plain"});
            fileWriter.write(output);
        }, errorCallback);
    }, errorCallback);
}

webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024,
    webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 1024, fsCallback, errorCallback),
errorCallback);
}

writeToLocal("test.txt", "hello world\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *virtual* file system. It might not actually represented by your files being somewhere in a folder, though of course the filesystem container is somewhere on the drive. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208984/is-it-possible-to-easy-get-normal-deobfuscated-access-to-all-files-in-a-sandbo).

As to how to get the data out of this filesystem, you can use `chrome.downloads` API to export the file.

---

Your question is ambiguously tagged; if it's a Chrome **App**, you could use `chrome.fileSystem` to work with real files instead.

Comment: Oh I see. Actually, I'm developing a chrome extension. But it seems that I can't use chrome.fileSystem for chrome extensions. I may turn it to chrome app instead of chrome extension. But, I still wonder where I can find the saved file... It should be located in the same directory showed on the page you linked to.

Comment: It might, but if it is it won't be named `test.txt`.

Comment: By design, you can't find the saved file. It's obfuscated to make it impractical to use it as a real file. Otherwise this API could be a vector to put bad files on the user's computer.

Comment: @W3Q To explain my remark about `chrome.downloads`, you can put a real file in your downloads folder (or a subfolder of it) if you need to export a file out.