# write a file using FileSystem API

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

I am trying to create a file using the File system API..i googled and i get a code

```
function onFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true},
      function(fileEntry) {
           fileEntry.getMetaData(function(md) {
            }, onError);

      },
      onError
  );
}

window.requestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 1024*1024 /*1MB*/, onFs, onError);
```

can any one say what is the fs which is passed as function argument..

Please refer me a good example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs` is a javascript object that allows you to make "system-like" level calls to a virtual filesystem.

So for instance you can use the `fs` object to create/get a reference to a file in the virtual filesystem with `fs.root.getFile(...)`. The third argument (in your case, the following lines of code from your above snippet) in the `.getFile(...)` method happens to be a callback for successful obtaining of a file reference.

```
function(fileEntry) {
       fileEntry.getMetaData(function(md) {
        }, onError);
}
```

That file reference (in your case it is called `fileEntry`) can have various methods called such as `.createWriter(...)` for writing to files, `.file(...)` for reading files and `.remove(...)` for removing files. Your method calls `.getMetaData(...)` which contains a file size and modification date.

For more specifics as well as some **good examples** on the html5 file-system api you may find the following article helpful [Exploring the File-System API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

The location of the files differs on the browser, operating system and storage type (persistent vs. temporary) but the following link has served to be quiet useful as well [Chrome persistent storage locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676584/where-does-persistent-file-system-storage-store-with-chrome)

Comment: i got "Error: SECURITY_ERR" when i do it in chrome...pls help

Comment: I found the [new question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21376738/1992129), My response on your `SECURITY_ERR` is in the second paragraph. I included example code and other explanations there as well