# Load local image, modify it and save back to same file

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

File input allows user to access a local file from browser. Is it possible to load a local file given by file input, modify it and save it back to same local file? I know that HTML5 allows creating writeable filesystem, but basically it seems to be abstract directory.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, I don't think the browser can overwrite the local file. Using the File-System API you could only copy the contents of the local file to the sandboxed [File-System API directory(found under various obfuscated file names)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11676584/1992129). All manipulation/saving would be done in AppData.

Perhaps displaying the modified image on the screen, right click, save-as to the given file location would also be suitable? (other than that I think you have to upload the image to a server and download it back again)