# File I/O in NACL SDK: where is file stored?

Tags: google-nativeclient

I have tried file I/O example Package in NACL SDK. That package runs successfully with options load file, save file, delete file. But it is unable to identify where the created file is stored. Where is the file stored?

Answer (score 1):

A Native Client plugin that does File IO normally creates a Chrome persistent file system. See this answer for how to find the directory holding it:

[Where does PERSISTENT file system storage store with chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676584/where-does-persistent-file-system-storage-store-with-chrome)