# Access Local Files in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

My extension needs to allow users to upload pdfs and then programmatically open those PDFs.

However, I want to do this without transmitting the PDFs from the user's computer. (And correspondingly without needing to send them back to their computer).

Is there any way at all to do this?  I know that there is a strong need to restrict access to local files.  Perhaps this is somehow achievable with some very sandboxed directory?  Somehow saving the files into the directory's local folder?

Relatedly what is the purpose of the match pattern for files? [see here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

Comment: You want to upload a local file PDF without transmitting it? How is that supposed to work (conceptually)? Is the server just supposed to guess at what the information in the file is?

Comment: It doesn’t need to go to a server.  “upload” may have been the wrong word.  Or may have been being used by analogy.  I want the user to be able to save files to a local directory in some and then retrieve those files again.

Comment: [HTML5 persistent file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676584/where-does-persistent-file-system-storage-store-with-chrome)?