# How do I move files from one directory to another using Chrome, without using ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, activex

I am trying to move a file from one directory to another using JavaScript.
I have already tried the code below...

```
function moveFile(){
   var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   var file = object.GetFile("C:\\wamp\\www\\phptest.php");
   file.Move("C:\\wamp\\");
   document.write("File is moved successfully");
}
```

... which yields this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined

I'm using Chrome, which doesn't support ActiveX.

I have also tried [IE-tab](https://www.ietab.net/) and [enabling ActiveX features](http://support.myvisionexpress.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/444/0/how-to-activate-activex-for-google-chrome--firefox-for-single-sign-on-feature-for-rd-web-access), with no success.
Is there another way to move a file from one directory to another, so that it will still work using Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Idan! What's the link to the `IE-tab` version, which you've already tried out? Would you please create a link to that? There seem to be a couple of IE Tab links online. I wasn't sure if you had tried out this one - http://ietab.mozdev.org - or a different one.

Comment: Hi! I have used this version: https://www.ietab.net/ .
The problem is that I am using sqlite, which is not supported with IE rendering.

Comment: Well sqlite is a database. IE Tab is switching rendering engines from Blink (with V8) to Trident. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) You'd still need to use PHP to grab form data & insert it into that RDBMS. You may want to look into using the `webkitRequestFileSystem` in Chrome. It won't work in Firefox. There are some gotchyas with using it (such as sandboxing), but Eric Bidelman (ebidel) has done some extensive work with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676584/where-does-persistent-file-system-storage-store-with-chrome